# Raspberry Pi Zero W Mini-HDMI to VGA connection problem

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero, output, pi-zero-w

The [SD card](http://www.ebay.com/itm/272654116794) I ordered a week ago showed up at my house today so I threw Raspbian on it with Win32DiskManager and attempted to boot up, but I was greeted without any kind of video signal. After doing a bit of reading, I figured this problem stemmed from the [Mini-HDMI to VGA converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LF7K1UK) I was using to connect to my monitor.

I've made sure the issue isn't the Pi itself by verifying that it shows up in Device Manager whenever I connect it to my computer via USB.

I've changed the following in the *config.txt* file but still no avail:

```
hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=47
config_hdmi_boost=7
framebuffer_width=1440
framebuffer_height=900
```

Unfortunately I have no other cables/monitors at the moment to test different connections on, so I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: As the most likely cause of the problem is as you have identified the cable, and you do not have another cable to test with, what is it you expect we can do?

Comment: Until you have a new cable you are left with two options SSH and VNC.